# searching with ajax and laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have a table called indents. I need to search and get details by entering a customer name. 
When I press a button it should return that customer details in the datatable, I am using ajax and laravel. When it worked it's just return last data only whenever i try to search a name

Index file

```
       <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#search_data').on('click', function () {
                $value = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '{{\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::to('search')}}',
                    data: {'search': $value},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#edpinfo').html(data);

                    }
                })

            })
        })
    </script>
    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({headers: {'csrftoken': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}});
    </script>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card m-b-30">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Indents</h4>

                    <input type="text" id="search" class="pull-right form-rounded">
                    <a href="{{route('edp')}}">
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left">Back</button>
                    </a>
                    <button id="search_data" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm pull-right">search</button>

                    <br>
                    <br><br>
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-bordered  table-responsive-lg">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Slno</th>
                            <th>Customer Name</th>
                            <th>Customer Phone Number</th>
                            <th>DateOfDelivery</th>
                            <th>Delivery At</th>
                            <th>Show</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
  <tbody id="edpinfo">
                    @foreach($indents as $indent)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->customer_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->phone_no}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->date_of_delivery}}</td>
                            <td>{{$indent->delivery_at}}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{route('edp.show',$indent->id)}}"><img src="assets/images/select.jpg"
                                                                                 class="imgsize"></a></td>

                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Controller file

```
    public function search(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->ajax()) {

            $output = "";
            $indents = indents::table('indents')
                ->where('customer_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')->get();
            foreach ($indents as $key => $indent) {

                        $output = '<tr>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->id . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->customer_name . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->phone_no . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->date_of_delivery . '</td>' .
                        '<td>' . $indent->delivery_at . '</td>' .
//                        '<td>'.'.<a href="{{route(\'edp.show\',$indent->id)}}">.'.'<img src="assets/images/select.jpg" class="imgsize">.'.'</a>.'.'</td>'.
                        '</tr>';

            }
            return Response($output);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you always overwrite the `$output` variable

So instead of `$output = '<tr>'`

Put `$output .= '<tr>'` (notice the dot)

Comment: i just did what you said then run the program and inspected with chrome web tool it shows  POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/search 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: you are posting to a route that isn't defined for POST requests, check your routes, and update the `search` route to POST, or update your ajax script to use GET

Comment: ohh s**t i had change the ajax get to post and i didn't  change the route file..my bad, thank you

Comment: if the output is good now, would you mind accepting my answer ?